# Update query insert zero in table in ci

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Update query insert zero in table everytime.

I have prtinted the query.From phpmyadmin the lastquery working fine.updated with same value
But when db active query then it has updating 0.

```
tbl_setitbl
set_id(primary key)
reference(text)`
```

Here is my code.

```
public function edit_set($id,$setvalue)
{
    $data = array('reference' => $setvalue);

    $this->db->where('set_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_setitbl', $data);

    if($this->db->affected_rows())
        return  true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: add some more details.

Comment: Just curious What is type of $setvalue??

Comment: $setvalue is string type @Nabin

Comment: some controller codes?? and i hope u tried echo $setvalue ??

Comment: ya ... its coming correctly ... but some unknown reason it wont work ..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code also.

$this->db->where('set_id', $id);
$this->db->update('tbl_setitbl', array('reference' => $setvalue));

echo $this->db->last_query();

UPDATE `tbl_setitbl` SET `reference` = 'hhhhhhhh' WHERE `set_id` = 1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry every one...
Get solved

actually the problem is in controller.

query has run two times as redirection has not doing properly

Answer (score -1):

see the result by using `$this->db->last_query()` then verify the sql code if it is similiar to the sql code that you have tried in phpmyadmin

Comment: this is a comment mate :)

Comment: ya i have used it.$this->db->last_query()
it is returning the sql that is ok .in php my admin it is working ... but when i am doing it by code it has updating 0.  to Ashok

$setvalue is string type @Nabin